# In a springboot application, how can I read values form application.yml, if I need to use them in my code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Following is my application.yml file

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
```

In one of my Java classes, I want to use the **port** number, which annotation I can use to achieve the same.

Comment: `@Value("${spring.mail.port}")` should do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [@Value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation:

```
@Value("${spring.mail.port}")
private Integer port;
```